# GetCategories ebay API call in django

Tags: python, django, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

i am stuck in getCateogory api call of ebay, given below is a django view which executes on a button click, i am getting desired output in backend on api call but it just returns a response as `<ebaysdk.response.Response object at 0x00FC6030>` on `print(result)`, how to get data on this API call in a variable so that it can be passed as a context and can be used in frontend in desired format.

Basically, i am developing an application to perform revise operation as in ebay, so want to fill all its drop down automatically as provided by ebay, for example, item condition field should automatically be filled with all valid drop down options which ebay supports and provides. So that i don't have to change it manually each time  ebay adds a new item condition. If is there any way to do it please let me know.

```
path = rootpath.detect()
    print(path)
    path = (path + "\\listing\\ebay.yaml")
    api = Connection(config_file=path, domain="api.sandbox.ebay.com", debug=True)
    GetCategoriesRequest = {
            "RequesterCredentials": {
                "eBayAuthToken": "xyz",
            },
            "CategorySiteID": "0",
            "DetailLevel": "ReturnAll",
            "LevelLimit": "1",
    }

    result = api.execute("GetCategories", GetCategoriesRequest)
    print("response of getcategories function is: ")
    print(result)
    print("get Category function worked!")
    ctx = {
        'result': result
    }
    return render(request, 'listing/reviseProduct.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the text of ebay's XML response do:
print(result.content)
or
print(result.dict())
to view it as a dictionary.